# Snorkeling places in Barcelona

Tags: spain, barcelona, diving, swimming

Do you know any good places to snorkel in Barcelona ?
I'm looking for a spot to snorkel that would not be crowded, I don't want to book a tour.
As my question could be subjective, I would like to precise that I'm not looking for the so-called best place to snorkel, but a one where I can see aquatic life, and not bump into too many people.

Comment: Are you looking for an excursion place to take you? Or are you looking for a beach? I just googled "snorkeling in barcelona" and it returned a bunch of places/results. **So the answer is "Yes".** Perhaps edit your question to make it more specific?

Comment: I've edited my question to make it clearer, I'm not looking for a tour, but browsing on other forums like reddit, I haven't find beaches nor rocky coves in Barcelona to go snorkel